# Unable To Download File using curl Python - Lambda Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am working on a lambda to create backup on pulse secure vtm, i am able to create backup but when i try to download the backup and put into s3, i get the size of file as 110.0B when the actual file size is 4770Kb. Here is the lambda

```
import boto3
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
from datadog_lambda.wrapper import datadog_lambda_wrapper
from datadog_lambda.metric import lambda_metric
from io import BytesIO

@datadog_lambda_wrapper
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Retrieve the username from Lambda environment variable
    vtm_username = os.environ.get("VTM_USERNAME")
    vtm_password = os.environ.get("VTM_PASSWORD")

    try:
        if not vtm_username or not vtm_password:
            # Send a Datadog metric with a value of 1 indicating an exception
            raise Exception("VTM username or password not found in environment variables")

        # Generate a backup name with today's date
        current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-d_%H-%M")
        backup_name = f"vtm-config-{current_date}"

        # Set the API URL for creating a backup with the updated name
        api_url = f"https://ip:9070/api/tm/8.3/status/local_tm/backups/full/{backup_name}"

        # JSON payload for creating the backup
        backup_payload = {
            "properties": {
                "backup": {
                    "description": "My vTM backup for today"
                }
            }
        }

        # Set up basic authentication using the retrieved credentials
        auth = (vtm_username, vtm_password)

        # Set the headers to indicate JSON content
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

        # Send a PUT request to create the backup
        response = requests.put(api_url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(backup_payload), verify=False, timeout=10)

        result = f"Response Status Code: {response.status_code}\n"
        result += f"Response Content:\n{response.text}"

        # Check if the backup was successfully created (you can customize this condition)
        if response.status_code == 201:
            # Download the exact same backup that was created
            backup_download_url = f"https://ip:9070/api/tm/8.3/status/local_tm/backups/full/{backup_name}"
            backup_data = requests.get(backup_download_url, auth=auth, stream=True, verify=False, timeout=10)

            if backup_data.status_code == 200:
                # Upload the backup data to S3
                s3 = boto3.client('s3')
                s3_bucket_name = "test-vtm-bucket"
                s3_object_key = f"{backup_name}.tar"
                s3.upload_fileobj(BytesIO(backup_data.content), s3_bucket_name, s3_object_key)

                result += f"\nBackup downloaded and uploaded to S3 as {s3_object_key}"
            else:
                raise Exception("Failed to download the backup")

    except Exception as e:
        result = f"Error: {str(e)}"

        # Send a Datadog metric with a value of 1 indicating an exception
        value = 1
        lambda_metric(
            "vtm-config-lambda-failure",  # metric
            value,  # value
            tags=[f"aws_account_id:{boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')}", f"env:testing"]
        )

    return result
```

Can someone please help as how can i download the full size file and upload to s3. iam very stuck with this. I am not able to use curl because i get an error "curl command not found". Looks like curl is not supported in amazon linux2

Comment: [How to upload a Python Requests content to S3 without saving the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71921493/174777)

Comment: Use `backup_data.raw` instead of `BytesIO(backup_data.content)`?